# Is there any way to specify that the return value of a method in an abstract class should be of the same type as the containing class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose I am writing some classes to perform simple mathematical operations, and that I have an abstract class `JNumber` with a method in it for adding on another number:

```
public abstract class JNumber
{
  public abstract JNumber add(JNumber addend);

  // etc.
}
```

The return value from `add` represents the sum of `this` with the parameter `addend`.

Now suppose that I have an abstract subclass (called `JFieldElement`) of `JNumber` which includes a method for division (I cannot have this method in the `JNumber` class, because you can't divide integers, for example).

```
public abstract class JFieldElement
  extends JNumber
{
  public abstract JFieldElement div(JFieldElement divisor);
}
```

Now suppose I am writing a procedure that will take instances *x,y,z* of some class extending `JFieldElement` and compute an expression like:

*x / (y + z)*

I might try:

```
JNumber w = y.add(z);
JNumber result = x.div(w);
```

However, if do that then I get an error - since the return type of `add` is `JNumber`, we have to declare `w` as a `JNumber`.  But then we cannot apply the function `div` to it, as that function needs to take in `JFieldElement`.

This would work if there was some way to specify that the `add` function should always return a value of the same type as whatever class it was called from.  Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: You said `JFieldElement` is subclass of `JNumber`. I don't see that.

Comment: You wrote "... because you can't divide integers". Actually you can.
10 divided by 3 is 3 and 1 is reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think generics should do the trick here:

```
public abstract class JNumber<N extends JNumber<N>>
{
  public abstract N add(N addend);
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to do it without generics, but this looks fairly clean.  Could you please explain why this works; I've stared at it for a bit, but I'm still not sure what's going on in `JNumber<N extends JNumber<N>>`.

Comment: How do I subclass this?  Is it `public class JFieldElement extends JNumber<JFieldElement>`?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to subclass this construct. I agree this notation can be confusing (it looks like recursion). You're roughly saying: I am declaring a type JNumber whose subclasses I can use like inside the body. Not sure if that makes sense, sorry.

Comment: OK.  Will I still need to use generics in some way in the subclasses?

Comment: Depends on what you want. It might be a good idea to generify JFieldElement in the same way `public abstract class JFieldElement<F extends JFieldElement<F>> extends JNumber<F>`, but that depends on your requirements. However, in order to implement what you asked for, there's no need to do so.

Answer (score 3):

```
public <T extends JNumber> T add(T addend);
```

Comment: This is the better answer, but it's cheap. How about elaborating on why this works?

Comment: Please can you explain the syntax for overriding this method?  Do I write `public JFieldElement add(JFieldElement addend)`?